# Missing $ inserted - trying to center within align

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \begin{center}
        \theta = ( \pi_0, \beta_0, \beta_1 )\\
        f(x_i, z_i, \theta) = 1(z_i = 0) \pi_0 f_0(x_i) + 1(z_i=1)\pi_1 f_1 (x_i)
    \end{center}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I keep getting these kind of errors, and notice it's always when I try to use a `\begin` inside another `\begin`.  I am VERY new to LaTeX, just got told I have to use it for my final and have no experience.

I feel like I am fundamentally misunderstanding something about TeX.

Comment: Could you edit in the code with your preamble? `align` and `align*` should center their equations by default. If you just want multiple equations to be centered, use the `gather` environment (and you won't need to write `\begin{center}`...`\end{center}`).

Comment: Editted it in with another example.

Answer (score 4):

- If you want each line of a group of equations to be centered, don't use an `align` or `align*` environment; instead, use a `gather` or `gather*` environment.
- Use the `align` and `align*` environments if you need to align the equations on some point, frequently an `=` symbol or other relational operator.

  Depending on the equations' content, it will in general be obvious if `gather` or `align` should be used.
- Whatever else you do, do *not* use a `center` environment inside a `gather` or `align` environment. The `center` environment is meant for text-mode material only.

A separate issue: you may want to think about using different outputs for `1` depending on whether it's a simple digit or represents the indicator function. The `amsmath` package provides the instruction `\DeclareMathOperator`, which is used below to set up a macro called `\One`. (I know, not very imaginative...) In the example below, `\One` outputs a bold `1` symbol. You're of course free to choose a different output. For instance, if you wanted a "double-struck" (aka "blackboard bold") look, you could load the `dsfont` package and declare `\DeclareMathOperator{\One}{\mathds{1}}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "align" and "gather" environments and "\DeclareMathOperator" macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\One}{\mathbf{1}} % symbol for indicator function
\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
   \theta = ( \pi_0, \beta_0, \beta_1 )\\
   f(x_i, z_i, \theta) = \One(z_i = 0) \pi_0 f_0(x_i) + \One(z_i=1)\pi_1 f_1 (x_i)
\end{gather*}

\begin{align*}
   \theta &= ( \pi_0, \beta_0, \beta_1 )\\
   f(x_i, z_i, \theta) &= \One(z_i = 0) \pi_0 f_0(x_i) + \One(z_i=1)\pi_1 f_1 (x_i)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```